# Executing async method on button click Blazor Server

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side, razor-components

I am trying to execute an asynchronous method when pressing a button. The code compiles without issue, but when the button is clicked the method is never called. I have used all the google fu i have at my disposal to no avail. Am I doing something wrong syntactically? Did i forget to import something or am i misunderstanding how this works?

```
  @foreach (Data.Course cor in CourseList)
                    { 
/...
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" @onclick="@(async () => await EnrollCourse(cor.CourseId))">
                                        Enroll
                                    </button>
}

@functions{
    private async Task EnrollCourse(int corid)
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        string userid = authState.User.Identity.Name;
        await _db.EnrollCourse(corid, userid);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/course/{corid}");
        
    }



}
```

Comment: string userid = authState.User.Identity.Name; Isnt this an email not not the Id?

Comment: How do you know the method has never been called ?

Comment: Yeah i verified it with the debugger that the method is never being executed, also the data does not get populated into the db

Comment: Does `@functions` still work?  What Blazor version are you using?

Comment: @HenkHoltermanI Ive tried in the code block and the function block, from what ive seen most people seem to put code like this in the function block. Whatever the latest version is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that comes around to this on google, i ended up setting the button to redirect to a different page that runs the code and redirects to the final page.

```
<div class="button">
    <a href="/enroll/@cor.CourseId">Enroll</a>
</div>
```

```
@page "/enroll/{course}"
@inject Data.CourseData _db
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser> userManager
@using System.Security.Claims


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string course { get; set; }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();

        var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(authState.User);
        if (user != null)
        {
            string userid = user.Id;
            await _db.EnrollCourse(Int32.Parse(course), userid);
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/course/" + Int32.Parse(course));


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note how I am collecting the User Id. I hope this helps. Your user manager may be of type `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` as well...

```
    @inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
    @using System.Security.Claims
    .....
    <AuthorizeView>
          @foreach (Data.Course cor in CourseList)
                    { 
/...
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" @onclick="@(async () => await EnrollCourse(cor.CourseId,context.User))">
                                        Enroll
                                    </button>
}
    </AuthorizeView>
@functions{
     private async Task EnrollCourse(int corid, ClaimsPrincipal identity)
     {

        var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(identity);

        var userid = user.Id;
        await _db.EnrollCourse(corid, userid);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/course/{corid}");
        
     }



}
```

Comment: Yeah, I dug through the docs and could not find a way to get the actual userid so i just had to settle on using the username instead. Im not sure what user id your implementation is referencing as in my database the user id is a string not an int. Im using the default authenticationstateprovider library via `@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider`

Comment: @MaxTE7 switch it to UserManager<ApplicationUser>  that is a string key. Individual accounts on blazer server-side must be ints. Injecting the AuthenticationStateProvider should work as well. If the user cant use the function why show the button. That is why I used <AuthorizeView> . It provided the context so there was no need to call GetAuthenticationStateAsync().

Comment: I am actually creating the buttons inside an authorized view, so i can use your method of getting the context, but, when I try to inject `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<ApplicationUser>` i get a namespace not found error. I am using the default user based authentication built into blazor if that helps

Comment: i figured it out. `var user = userManager.GetUserAsync(identity);` should be `var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(identity);`. Then the user is retrieved properly

Comment: FYI:  var userId = identity.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value; works on client-side

Comment: @MaxTE7 - that explains how nothing was added, not how (as you 'verified') the method was not being called.